# Why am I getting a "java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 5 out of bounds for length 5" error for my findPosition method?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, error-handling

First Class which is giving me the error. I'm to make an array with the letters A-Z, and then have the user input the keys which it takes and compares each character's position in the array of the key with the position of a user inputted string

```
import java.util.*;
    public class Encrypt{
        private Square plain1;
        private Square plain2;
        private Square Encrypt1;
        private Square Encrypt2;

    public Encryption(String key1, String key2) {
        plain1 = new Square();
        plain2 = new Square();
        Encrypt1= new Square(key1);
        Encrypt2= new Square(key2);
    } 


    public String encrypt(String msg) {
        String EmpS = "";
        String STR = "";

        for(int i = 0; i < message.length(); i+=2){
            char iMsg = message.charAt(i);
            char iMsg2 = message.charAt(i+1);
            int[] posRay = plain1.findPosition(iMsg);
            int[] posRay2 = plain2.findPosition(iMsg2);
            String answer = "" + Encrypt1.getChar(posRay[0], posRay2[1]);
            String Combined = "" + answer;
            String answer2 = "" + Encrypt2.getChar(posRay2[0], posRay[1]);
            String Combined2 = "" + answer2;

            String BothCom = Combined + Combined2;
            STR = STR.concat(BothCom);

        return STR;
        }
        return STR;
    }
```

2nd class that is responsible for the array

```
public class Square {
    private char[][] matrix;
public Square() {
        arr= new char[5][5];
        int ascii= 65;
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++){
                arr[i][j] = (char) ascii;
                ascii++;
                }
            }
        }
}
public int[] findPosition(char Chart) {
        int[] position= new int[2];
        position[0] = -1;
        popositions[1] = -1;
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
            for (int j = 0; i < 5; j++){
                if(matrix[i][j] == Chart){
                posistion[0] = i;
                position[1] = j;
                return position;
                }
            }
        }
```

I'm getting this as an error (everything else works), and I've tried changing the size of the array and tweaking the for loop, but I'm still unsure why I'm getting an error what's the issue?:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 5 out of bounds for length 5
    at Square.findPosition(Square.java:91)
    at Encrypt.encrypt(Encrypt.java:45)
    at IO.printResults(IO.java:101)
    at Lab.main(Lab.java:26)
```

Comment: My guess is that field `matrix` was initialized with a size `<= 5` in at least one of its dimentions. --- Please [edit] the post and add a [MRE].

Comment: Please post a [mcve] that compiles. We can't tell which of the errors that makes it not compile are in your original code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `for (int j = 0; i < 5; j++){`

That's supposed to be `j < 5`. The `i < 5` condition is true and remains true no matter how often this loops, thus, you end up with `j = 5` and that index doesn't exist.

NB: I'm just guessing. This *clearly* is not the code you actually wrote, given that it has a ton of typos in it and wouldn't compile without fixing *all of them*.

Next time paste the actual code that causes the actual error, not... whatever happened here. Did you type it over by hand? Oof.

Answer (score 0):

the field matrix is not initialized. i mean where are the matrix been filled in the class Square?
another thing: what is arr in the constructor come from?
now you gonna know it.